# Entity Framework Core and column level SQL Server encryption with stored procedures, how to map properties the right way?

Tags: c#, encryption, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2022

I have made work SQL Server encryption/decryption using stored procedures, symmetric keys using Entity Framework Core.

I am able to save the object in the database, I pass the `SSNumber` parameter to the stored procedure, it encrypts it and stores it in `SSNumberEncrypted`.

I also coded a stored procedure to get the record, I set the property `SSNumber = DecryptByKey(SSNumberEncrypted)`. If I run it in SSMS, it works and I get the `SSNumber`, but when I execute the stored procedure from C#, the property value is always null, because of the `NotMapped` attribute.

Is there a way that I can accomplish this?

```
public class Test 
{
      public long Id { get; set; }
      [NotMapped]
      public string SSNumber { get; set; }
      public byte[] SSNumberEncrypted { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public class Test 
{
      public long Id { get; set; }
      [NotMapped]
      public string SSNumber { get=>DecryptByKey(SSNumberEncrypted); 
                              set=>.......; }
      public byte[] SSNumberEncrypted { get; set; }
}
```